# Problems to get the data from Ionic Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, storage, ionic-storage

I have a problem with the Ionic-Storage.
I want to save a boolean into the storage. The action is triggered by an ion-toggle. If the toggle is on= true, otherwise false. So I have create a service, which can save and get the data.

Storage-Service.ts

```
const ITEM_KEY = 'modal-myworkplace';
[...]


async setItem(value){
  const res = await this.storage.set(ITEM_KEY,value)
   console.log(res)
 }

  async getItem() {
      await this.storage.get(ITEM_KEY).then((name) => {
          console.log('The Keyvalue is: '+name)
      })
  }
```

Here is the problem...
I want to get this data in an component. Like this:
Component.ts

```
let saveWorkplace: boolean;
[...]
async setData(){
    await this.storage.getItem().then((name) => {
      console.log("Key: "+ name)
    })
  }
```

I want to get the value from the Storage (true or false) and this should then be defined in saveWorkplace.

If I console.log this properties in the Component.ts I get an undefined object. But if i console.log the property in Storage.ts I get an Value([See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG66f.png))

I dont know how I can get only the Value true or false.

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: Are you getting any error? this should work if you did your dependence injection right in Component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you track what you return (Promise or value) and update your code accordingly:

Service:

```
setItem(value):Promise<any> {

  this.storage.set(ITEM_KEY,value) // you can use .then here to check saved value.

}

getItem():Promise<any> {

  return this.storage.get(ITEM_KEY);

}
```

In your component since you are returning promise you can use async:

```
async getData() {

  return this.saveWorkplace = await this.storage.getItem()

};
```

Now if you feel the need to leverage async method and read these values at the page initialization time (ngOnInit), you can do so this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData().then( saved => {
        console.log(saved)
        // the rest of init code that depends on the value;

    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!
So that the component retrieves this each time, I have added it additionally in ngOnInit.

Comment: Cool! Yeah minimizing work with async things like Storage is a way to go!

Comment: Do you have an idea how you can realize, how you can call async methods in ngOnInit? Unfortunately you cannot add an "await" to ngOnInit.

And in a lot of cases you need this.

Comment: yeah let me add that

Comment: added "return" to getData method and how you can call it now inside ngOnInit. You can also check Stackoverflow for answers on how to call async methods within ngOnInit and you can potentially just add "async" in front of ngOnInit and do await as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getItem()` is not returning the value. Change it to:

```
async getItem() {
    return await this.storage.get(ITEM_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your post! Unfortunately with Console.log in the component.ts I now get the output of a "ZoneAwarePromise".
The thing is, I need there the value "true" or "false"
How i can get this?

Here's what I tried: 
`await this.storage.get(ITEM_KEY).then((res)=>{
          return res
      });`
Unfortunately without success... But if I console.log "res", true or false comes out.

Comment: what is "this.storage" in your service?